# php preg replace using $1 in as associative

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-replace

The problem is that it is not showing or evaluating the variable when using $1 as the index of an array.

```
        Data Table
        fname
        kim
        bob


$exp="<input type='text' name='fname' value='\"fname\"'>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $dstr=preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', $row["$1"], $exp); 
    echo $dstr;
}
```

This result in a blank text field.

```
<input type='text' name='fname' value=''> x2
```

Desire result:

```
<input type='text' name='fname' value='kim'><input type='text' name='fname' value='bob'>
```

Comment: That's not how `$1` works. It's supposed to appear in a literal replacement string for pcre to consume as placeholder. It doesn't work in PHP context. Here specifically your `$row` database result doesn't have a field/key named `['$1']`.

Answer (score 1):

Second argument of preg_replace have to be a string. It's template which would replace matched string. You do not know template before preg_replace.

So, you need to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Something like this:

```
$dstr=preg_replace(
    '/"([^"]+)"/', 
    function(array $matches)use($row)
        {return $row[$matches[1]];}, 
    $exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this:

```
$exp = "<input type='text' name='fname' value='blahblah' />";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
  foreach($row as $v){
    $dstr = preg_replace('/^(.+)blahblah(.+)$/', "$1$v$2", $exp); 
    echo $dstr;
  }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend changing to Object Oriented PHP and using `new mysqli` instead of mysql. This is a functional example.